# Does $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{p_n}\right)$ diverge?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, infinite-product

$p_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ prime number.

This looks like Euler's product for zeta function, but I don't know if they are related.

Comment: Do you know the Euler product of $\zeta(s)/\zeta(2s)$ ? What do you get when $s\to 1^+$ ?

Comment: $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{p_n}\right)$ diverges iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_n}$ diverges

Comment: @reuns Your comment is a way to think about the problem, but logically there is a difference between the divergence of $\prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(1 + \frac 1 {p_n}\right)$ and the divergence of $\lim_{s \rightarrow 1^+}\prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(1 + \frac 1 {p_n^s}\right)$.

Comment: If the former product converges then the latter limit is bounded above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does diverge.

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{p_n}\right) \ge 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_n}$$

the RHS of which is well-known to diverge.

In fact, $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{p_n} = \Omega(\log \log N)$.

Comment: How is this though? As $\sum_{p \le N} \frac{1}{p} < \sum_{j =1}^N \frac{1}{j} = \theta(\log N)$

Comment: Section 4.8 of Tom M. Apostol's _Introduction to Analytic Number Theory_ gives a proof for that, which is based on Shapiro's Tauberian theorem.

Comment: @Travor Liu that sum doesnt seem right. It is upper bounded by a sum that is only $\log N$ for starters

Comment: Oops, that was a mistake. It should have been $\sum_{p\le N}\frac1p=\Theta(\log\log N)$